# Запуск теста одновременно в двух разных браузерах(selenide)

Tags: java, selenide

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется проблема с запуском теста на двух браузерах, одновременно в 2 потока.

login.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Login"  thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
<parameter name="rootLogin" value="root"/>
<parameter name="rootPassword" value="admin"/>
<test name="Login Test Firefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Login Test Chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Сам тест:

```
public class LoginTest extends AbstractTest {
@Parameters({"rootLogin", "rootPassword", "browser"})
@Test
public void TestLoginOk(String login, String password, String browser) {
    openLoginPage(browser)
            .loginToSite(login, password)
            .checkSuccessfulLogin(login);
}
```

Класс с запуском драйвера:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.135.555:8888";

public static LoginPage openLoginPage(String browser) {
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        Configuration.browser = browser;
    }
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
        Configuration.browser = browser;
    }
    open(URL);
    return new LoginPage();
}
```

В итоге запускаются либо 2 хрома, либо 2 лисы
Вопрос: как можно регулировать порядок запуска тестов из xml и собственно главный вопрос, как все-таки заставить запускать 1 хром и 1 мозилу.

Answer (score 0):

Не параллельте запуск в разных браузерах таким образом. 
У этого способа есть ряд недостатков.

Лучше сделайте два таска в градле (или два профайла в мавене) и запускайте их по отдельности:

```
./gradle test-chrome
./gradle test-firefox
```

В случае с (прости господи) мавеном:

```
mvn test -Pchrome
mvn test -Pfirefox
```